# Django not displaying images from media directory

Tags: django

There are user avatars which are uploaded by user and stored in /media/users. In test environment these images are showing properly, but on production with identical code we have blank field instead of image and site.com/media/users/image_name.jpg redirects to other page, i. e. cannot find image. We cannot debug production server so I want to ask what possible causes can this behavior have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there a possibility that you are not serving the /media files using a webserver (like nginx) and the requests go to django app which (with the DEBUG flag turned off) doesn't handle media_url ?

Comment: Is there simple way to log that Django serves media or not?

Comment: hmm i don't know if that's easy, but if you could try importing urls like this (using manage.py shell):

```
from myproject.urls import urlpatterns
print(urlpatterns)
```

then with DEBUG turned off, you shouldn't see /media in the list.

if there is no /media on the list, then you would have to re-configure your webserver to support /media and serve files from this directory